# Add id to image inside views

Tags: views, theming, media

I have created a grid in views in which there are stored webshops (it's for a website on which you can find all kind of webshops). It shows a picture, a title and a bodytext for each webshop. And now I would like to edit the images only for that page in a seperate id. 
Only I have no idea how i should add an id for the css of the image, how is this possible in drupal, css or php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the "NID" field to your view's fields, (as the first entry, for reasons I won't get in to here),  you can then use the "rewrite output" function to attach a unique CSS ID using the NID to your image.

Comment: I get your point, but I can't add it to my <img> line, only override it with the rewrite output function

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution you were talking about;) thanks!